# Scraping futures data with R

Tags: javascript, r, httr, rselenium

I am working on scraping energy futures data from ICE and need some help with the js involved.

I'm working on [ICE Futures](https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/254) data and, in particular I want to access the NGX FIN FF, FP for 7A, (CA/GJ), AB-NIT contract settlement. So, I want their dropdown menu to look like this, and then click submit and read to a dataframe in R.
[image: drop down menu configuration]

I'm stuck at the "do I need to use Rselenium to do this?" stage of the problem.

I've looked through devtools to see if I can parse the execution, but my JS is weak so I'm hoping that one of you can point me in the right direction.

The button is executing jquery.min.js but that's as far as I can get at this point.

Unfortunately, I've tried many sample Rselenium code snippets, but have not been able to get one to run without error yet.  Still working on it, but if anyone has a quick answer that would help it would be much appreciated.  Will update as I go if I get further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it figured out, thanks to a friend:

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)
library(janitor)


ngx_read<-function(series_id,settlement)
{
query = list(
  htmlReport="",
  reportId=254,
  criteria.group="Natural Gas",
  criteria.selectedMarket=series_id,
  criteria.selectedTimePeriod=settlement,
  rcMode=2
  )
#Settlement can be:
  #"Current Settlement"
  #Previous Day Settlement
  #Day-2 Settlement
  #Day-3 Settlement
  #Day-4 Settlement

html_doc<-read_html(POST("https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/ngx/DailySettlementPrices.shtml", body = query))

html_nodes(html_doc, "table")[[1]]%>%html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% clean_names()%>%
  mutate(begin_date=ymd(begin_date),end_date=ymd(end_date),net_oi=as.numeric(gsub(",","",net_oi)),
         settle=settlement,date=Sys.Date())
}

ngx_data<-ngx_read("NGX Fin FF, FP for 7A, (CA/GJ), AB-NIT","Previous Day Settlement")
```